# Failing to retrieve friends' profile picture and displaying it in a tableview iOS Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, sdk

I am trying to display the users facebook friends' profile picture in a tableview. I've managed to retrieve the name of the friends but i'm having a hard time fetching the friend's profile picture.

Here's my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

   if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {
       [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"/me" parameters:@{@"fields":@"name"}]
       startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
       if (!error) {
             NSLog(@"fetched user:%@", result);
       }
     }];
   }
   FBSDKProfilePictureView *profilePictureview = [[FBSDKProfilePictureView alloc]initWithFrame:_topProfilePic.frame];
   //[profilePictureview setProfileID:result[@"id"]];

   [_topProfilePic addSubview:profilePictureview];

   UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:_topProfilePic.bounds
                                               byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerAllCorners cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(1000.0, 1000.0)];

   // Create the shape layer and set its path
   CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];

   maskLayer.frame = _topProfilePic.bounds;
   maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;

   // Set the newly created shape layer as the mask for the image view's layer
   _topProfilePic.layer.mask = maskLayer;

   [super viewDidLoad];

}


-(void)getFriends {

   FBSDKGraphRequest *requestFriends = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                                     initWithGraphPath:@"/me/friends"
                                     parameters:@{@"fields" :    @"name,picture.type(small)"}
                                     HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
   [requestFriends startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection,
                                             id result,
                                             NSError *error) {
    if (!error && result)
    {
        NSArray *allFriendsResultData = [result objectForKey:@"data"];

        if ([allFriendsResultData count] > 0)
        {
            for (NSDictionary *friendObject in allFriendsResultData)
            {
                NSString *friendName = [friendObject objectForKey:@"name"];
                NSString *friendID = [friendObject objectForKey:@"id"];
                NSString *friendPhoto = [friendObject objectForKey:@"picture.type(small)"];

                CFriend *newFriend = [CFriend addFriendWithName:friendName FriendID:friendID friendPhoto:friendPhoto];

                if (!self.objects) {
                    self.objects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                }
                [self.objects addObject:newFriend];
                NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:_objects.count-1 inSection:0];
                [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
                [self.tableView reloadData];
            }
        }
    }
   }];
 }

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
   return 1;
 }

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
   return self.objects.count;
 }

 -(void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
   [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
   // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
 }
 -(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{

   return @"VEXI";
 }
 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

   CFriend *objects = self.objects[indexPath.row];
   UILabel *overskriftlbl = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:201];
   overskriftlbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [objects friendName]];

   UIImageView *thumbnailImageView = (UIImageView* )[cell viewWithTag:202];

   thumbnailImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[objects friendPhoto]];
   UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:thumbnailImageView.bounds
                                               byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerAllCorners

                                                    cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(10.0, 10.0)];
   // Create the shape layer and set its path
   CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
   maskLayer.frame = thumbnailImageView.bounds;
   maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;

   // Set the newly created shape layer as the mask for the image view's layer
   thumbnailImageView.layer.mask = maskLayer;
   return cell;
}
```

EDIT:

I have now managed to retrieve the graph url for the images. However they don't load into the imageview... see code below:

```
    - (void)getFriends {

FBSDKGraphRequest *requestFriends = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                                     initWithGraphPath:@"/me/friends"
                                     parameters:@{@"fields" : @"name,picture.type(small)"}
                                     HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[requestFriends startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection,
                                             id result,
                                             NSError *error) {
    if (!error && result)
    {
        NSArray *allFriendsResultData = [result objectForKey:@"data"];



        if ([allFriendsResultData count] > 0)
        {
            for (NSDictionary *friendObject in allFriendsResultData)
            {
                NSString *friendName = [friendObject objectForKey:@"name"];
                NSString *friendID = [friendObject objectForKey:@"id"];
                NSString *friendPhoto= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?type(small)​", friendID];
                CFriend *newFriend = [CFriend addFriendWithName:friendName FriendID:friendID friendPhoto:friendPhoto];

                if (!self.objects) {
                    self.objects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                }
                [self.objects addObject:newFriend];
                NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:_objects.count-1 inSection:0];
                [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
                NSLog(@"%@", friendPhoto);
                [self.tableView reloadData];
            }
        }
    }
}];
   }

    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
return 1;
    }

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return self.objects.count;

    }
    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    - (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{

return @"VEXI";
    }
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

CFriend *objects = self.objects[indexPath.row];
NSString *imageData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [objects friendPhoto]];

UILabel *overskriftlbl = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:201];
overskriftlbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [objects friendName]];

UIImageView *thumbnailImageView = (UIImageView*)[cell viewWithTag:202];
UIImage *profilePic = [UIImage imageNamed:imageData];
thumbnailImageView.image = profilePic;

//NSLog(@"%@", imageData);


UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:thumbnailImageView.bounds
                                               byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerAllCorners

                                                     cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(10.0, 10.0)];
// Create the shape layer and set its path
CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
maskLayer.frame = thumbnailImageView.bounds;
maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;

// Set the newly created shape layer as the mask for the image view's layer
thumbnailImageView.layer.mask = maskLayer;
return cell;
    }
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: can you print this `friendPhoto`

Comment: Using the type modifier on the picture field does not change the key under which the picture is returned. Pretty sure your line `NSString *friendPhoto = [friendObject objectForKey:@"picture.type(small)"];` is wrong therefor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this URL to fetch that picture

http://graph.facebook.com/IdOfTheUer/picture?type=normal

Comment: But then I have to break up the url and insert the array of id's, is that possible?

Comment: if ([allFriendsResultData count] > 0)
        {
            for (NSDictionary *friendObject in allFriendsResultData)
            {
                NSString *friendName = [friendObject objectForKey:@"name"];
                NSString *friendID = [friendObject objectForKey:@"id"];
                NSString *friendphoto=[nsstring stringwithformat:@“http://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?type=normal”, friendID];

Comment: Cool, I'll give it a go!

Comment: Although maybe I have to use a webview or view instead of uiimageview?

Comment: NSLog(@"%@", [objects friendPhoto]);

Comment: This is outputting the correct url but i'm not able to load them in the imageview... Ideas?

Comment: UIImageView *thumbnailImageView = (UIImageView* )[cell viewWithTag:202];
    thumbnailImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[objects friendPhoto]];

Answer (score 1):

Here is my code to retrive all friend from Facebook. You can create a custom method with it.

```
-(void)getFacebookFriend
{
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    [params setObject:@"id, first_name, last_name, middle_name, name, email, picture" forKey:@"fields"];
    [params setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"500"] forKey:@"limit"];

    [[FBRequest requestWithGraphPath:@"me/taggable_friends" parameters:params HTTPMethod:nil] startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error)
     {
         NSArray *aryFriend = result[@"data"];
         [yourFriendArrat addObjectsFromArray:aryFriend];
         NSLog(@"%lu",(unsigned long)aryFriend.count);
         NSMutableDictionary *dicPaging = result[@"paging"];


             NSLog(@"Final Array count:    %lu",(unsigned long)arrayFriend.count);
             [yourTable reloadData];
         }];
}
```

You can use below code in your **cellForRow** method to download picture.

```
NSDictionary *dic = yourArray[indexPath.row];
NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",dic[@"picture"][@"data"][@"url"]];
```

I am successfully getting friend list from facebook. Hope it will helpfull for you.

Comment: Why taggable_friends?

Comment: It will return logged in user's friend. If you go with "friends" then it will return those friend who are authorized the application.

Comment: If answer is helpful for you then you can accept it. So it can help for other also.

Comment: Would you consider giving me more code? I'm unsure as to where I am suppose to put your code. @Nirmalsinh

Comment: @AndreasOL I updated my answer. You can user method to retrive fb friend when you want and you can download the image in cellForRow method.

Answer (score -1):

You can replace the @"me/friends" to @"me/taggable_friends".

```
FBSDKGraphRequest *requestFriends = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]initWithGraphPath:@"/me/taggable_friends" parameters:@{@"fields" : @"name,picture.type(small)"} HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
```

Comment: is not a answer, already questioner got the URL , problm is need to load i tableview, can you modify ur answer, i m not assign the downvot

Comment: No, you can not, because taggable_friends is for tagging people _only_, it is not a “workaround” to get a full list of friends for any other purpose.